# .read .write .replace string elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have these 2 functions (serialize and deserialize) in Javascript (below) and I want to change it to jQuery. I am wondering what would the right replacement for read and write in jQuery. Read and write strings are from and to a Textarea. This is part of Openlayers vector formats, getting geometries into / from OL map canvas.

Serialize is outputing the geometries from mapcanvas to textarea.

```
function serialize(feature) {
            var type = document.getElementById("formatType").value;

            var pretty = document.getElementById("prettyPrint").checked;

            var str = formats['out'][type].write(feature, pretty);

            str = str.replace(/,/g, ', ');

            document.getElementById('output').value = str;
}
```

Deserialize is reading string from Textarea into OL mapcanvas.

```
function deserialize() {
    var element = document.getElementById('text');


    var type = document.getElementById("formatType").value;
    var features = formats['in'][type].read(element.value);
    var bounds;
    if(features) {
        if(features.constructor != Array) {
            features = [features];
        }
        for(var i=0; i<features.length; ++i) {
            if (!bounds) {
                bounds = features[i].geometry.getBounds();
            } else {
                bounds.extend(features[i].geometry.getBounds());
            }

        }
        vectors.addFeatures(features);
        map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
        var plural = (features.length > 1) ? 's' : '';
        element.value = features.length + ' feature' + plural + ' added';
    } else {
        element.value = 'Bad input ' + type;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Again, I am asking about the read and write function equivalent in jQuery. These 2 lines:

```
var str = formats['out'][type].write(feature, pretty);

var features = formats['in'][type].read(element.value);
```

Comment: If you are asking how to set/get the value of a textarea with ID="foo", you can use $('#foo').val('bar') to set, $('#foo').val() to get.

Comment: No, I am not asking the DOM. I am asking about the read and write. Is there any equavalent function in jQuery?  var str = formats['out'][type].write(feature, pretty); and these:  var features = formats['in'][type].read(element.value);

Comment: what do those functions currently do? are they built-ins I've somehow never heard of?

Comment: What functions are you asking, the read, write and replace? or the deserialise and serialize? Ask you can see, the read, write and replace is part of the variable string. If I am not mistaken it is part of the Javascript.

Comment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

Comment: The above link is the OpenLayers example and the functions are used in  Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

to get the text in a text area

```
$("#myTextArea").val();
```

To set it to something

```
$("#myTextArea").val("Foo bar.");
```

Comment: I was not asking about the DOM. I ask these: var str = formats['out'][type].write(feature, pretty); and var features = formats['in'][type].read(element.value);